# How to use redirectReponse with NSURLConnection in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection

I'm using some pretty standard URL code in Cocoa - basically

```
result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:query 
                               returningResponse:&response
                                           error:&serverError];
```

However I cannot see how to detect when the query (which is the URL) responds with a redirect - I want to be able to process the data differently if the result is not the HTML code that I expect due to a redirect - in which case I want to capture and parse the redirected URL

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use the synchronous version? You get a lot more control with the asynchronous version, including the redirect callback described in [Apple's overview of NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-160106).